# System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser (WPF) и HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser, htmlagilitypack

Как из этого контрола получить html страницу, чтобы ее можно было загрузить
в HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument ?
По событию LoadCompleted можно плучить доступ к свойству:
    var doc = this.webBrowser.Document;
Но дело в том, что свойство это имеет тип object. Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство WebBrowser.Document возвращает COM-объект Internel Explorer'a. Можно пойти 2 путями.

Использовать `dynamic` для обращения к свойствам COM-объекта:

```
dynamic doc = wb.Document;
string html = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Или же добавить референс на `Microsoft.mshtml` и привести к типу `HTMLDocument`:

```
var doc = wb.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
string html = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем то, что ожидалось. Я специально обратил внимание, что WebBrowser из WPF, а не из WinForms. У него свойство Document имеет тип object, т.е. доступны только: ToString(), GetHashCode() и прочее.

Comment: @Bulson обратите внимание на тип dynamic, это не тоже самое что var или object. Document возвращает object так как должен вернуть COM объект, это есть в документации, читайте внимательнее,  а dynamic позволяет сразу работать с ним как с объектом, но вы сами должны знать свойства и методы этого объекта. Второй вариант с явным приведением к нужному типу.

Comment: @Bulson а также обращаю ваше внимание на то, что и WinForms и WPF предоставляют обертку над одним и тем же COM-компонентом движка Internet Explorer.

Comment: Да, спасибо за пояснения @rdorn я все понял. Первый вариант прекрасно работает. Второй тоже будет работать.

Comment: Добавьте информацию из комментариев в ответ для полноты, т.к. со временем количество людей знающих или хотя бы интересующихся тонкостями внутреннего устройства только уменьшается к сожалению.

Comment: @rdorn спасибо, добавил

Comment: @ Zergatul Пользуюсь VS2017. Менеджер ссылок предлагает три варианта ссылок Microsoft.mshtml (у всех одинаковое название, разница лишь в местах хранения) не понятно какую из них нужно выбрать. Не подскажите какая именно из них для чего подходит. (Я собирался использовать ее в WPF проекте.)

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko смотрите на версию, а не на название. Возможно они соответствуют разным версиям интернет эксплорера.

Comment: @Zergatul номер версии один и тот же для всех трех вариантов. Единственная разница это расположение файлов. Все три хранятся в разных местах.